# create dataframe using items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

```
price
             price       
date    
2010-01-04  30.572827     
2010-01-05  30.7725684    
2010-01-06  30.668541     
2010-01-07  30.08772827
```

How can i create the first difference in a dataframe for all variables in a list?

```
listxx = ["price"]
for x in listxx:
    globals().update({f'{x}_first_diff':globals()[x].diff().dropna()})
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: You need to convert the `dtype` of `x`, before using `diff`

Answer (score 0):

Your code already works, but if you use `.diff()` you have to specify what the source for the difference shall be, in your example you might have to either specify the column in the dataframe or use the `axis` parameter.

```
import pandas as pd
your_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2010-01-04', 1: '2010-01-05', 2: '2010-01-06', 3: '2010-01-07'},
 'price': {0: 30.572827, 1: 30.7725684, 2: 30.668540999999998, 3: 30.08772827}})

listxx = ["your_df"]
for x in listxx:
    globals().update({f'{x}_first_diff':globals()[x]['price'].diff().dropna()})
```